# Conditionally getting the type of interface property in typescript

Tags: typescript, conditional-statements, extends, keyof

Here is my interface:

```
interface Responses {
  200:{
    foo:number;
  };
  204:{
    bar:number;
  };
}
```

I can get any of the property type as follow:

```
type TypeFor200 = Responses['200'];
```

However I would like to make it conditional so that if `200` property is not exist in the interface, it should return the type for `204`, something like this:

```
type AnyType= Responses extends 200 ? Responses['200'] : Responses['204'] ;
```

If both `200` and `204` exist, the above example will work, otherwise will throw an error complaining that the property does not exist.

Note that I cannot make a change to `Responses` interface since it is in an autogenerated file.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

The conditional type you're going for seems to be a red flag for me. I can't think of a construct where this would be useful or necessary. TypeScript already errors when you try to access a property that does not exist on an interface.

```
interface Responses {
  200: {
    foo: number
  }
}

type NoContentResponse = Responses['204'];
                                   ^^^^^
              Property '204' does not exist on type 'Responses'.
```

– [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQM4AcD2IObIDeAsAFDLIBMADDQFzHmWUw46MgCuAtgEbRmyAL7lRZcmACeWFADkcAYTyRw6bHgLIAvGky58mANoByWgBYTAXQDcQA)

So you should just annotate the types correctly or break down your types so that you can use each fragment and compose them as necessary as opposed to use a conditional type like what you're trying to go for. However I can't think of everything so maybe you really have a use case for a conditional type.

The conditional you want is `<key> extends keyof <interface>`. This checks for the existence of a key. It would have to be constructed into a generic type. Something like this:

```
type Foo<A, B, C> = B extends keyof A ? A[B] :
                    C extends keyof A ? A[C] :
                    undefined;
```

An example with the resultant types is below:

```
interface OkResponse {
  200:{
    foo:number;
  };
}

interface NoContentResponse {
  204:{
    bar:number;
  };
}

interface NotAResponse {}

type OkAndNoContent = OkResponse & NoContentResponse;
type NoContent = NoContentResponse;

type Foo<A, B, C> = B extends keyof A ? A[B] :
                    C extends keyof A ? A[C] :
                    undefined;

type TypeForOk = Foo<OkAndNoContent, 200, 204>; // { foo: number; }
type TypeForNoContent = Foo<NoContent, 200, 204>; // { bar: number; }
type TypeForNotAResponse = Foo<NotAResponse, 200, 204> // undefined
```

– [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIGsBKEDOAHAexBxQG8BYAKGWQCYAGegLgupuRgIKZAFcBbAEbQA3FRoBfMZQlUqoSLEQoAcgQDCRSOGz4iJZKxoMALC3HtBcKDwHCo0ydNmV54aPCTI1YAIK7CYjIXKjAATzwUDF8QABM1TXdwZABeNCxcQIMAMm8NLQgdTP0IaXDIvMTtMFTKgqK9IOlQiJQAMS4AHl8AGmQAIT71AD5a-uQIAA9tWJxkdAgwghhkX2QAflWAbX6AXWQmC3Zjk9P1CenC2fnF5dWN7fV9w7ZTt5PeOIgYUAhY5so5RQABVWh0oBhah0CJ1onEEvUwH0GPRkfQTMMRMgAPTYwwcLhMZB8ISiZAuIHIUGRcEIpI1NLQzp06po1F0dGYnF40jIKw2Yl2MkU1pUsEEKA+fzFIJQrpSgIlNlojHc5CfWLfX6xIA)

You can't do `extends keyof` outside of a generic type because TypeScript has enough type information to give you an error, another reason why this seems to be a red flag for me:

```
interface NoContentResponse {
  204:{
    bar:number;
  };
}

type TypeForNoContent = '200' extends keyof NoContentResponse ?
  NoContentResponse['200'] : NoContentResponse['204'];
                    ^^^^^
 Type '"200"' cannot be used as an index type.
```

– [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIHsDC7wXAJQgGcAHHIlAbwFgAoZZAJgAYAWALhvoeQCM4o7EAFcAtr2gBuOgwC+02rLp0wATxIoAKuogAxdFAzZc4ZAF5kAchbNLyCAA9IIACZFkAawir0MNFhxnMEJSchQAfhl-YyCQshAKAG1rZlsAXWR2aMC8YOJ4pJTWSzTJIA)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Splitting the interface would not be an option for me because it is in an autogenerated file. Otherwise, I think your suggestion is simple.